# Action Bar for Android 2.3

Tags: android, eclipse

I followed the steps given in http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html#add-library
During the step: Create a library project(Adding libraries with resources), for the v7 appcompat project, I see project titled appcompat instead of android-support-v7-appcompat. Where am I going wrong? Please help.

Answer:I realized for older versions of Android SDK we get appcompat titled project not the v7 one.

Comment: have you imported library project from extras folder?

Comment: Yes I did. I hope you are referring to steps 1 and 2 of Adding libraries with resources.